# array initialization expected expression objective-C xcode 5.1.1

Tags: objective-c, arrays, macos

I'm using the selector for Mac OS X Cocoa App and files of class for Mac OS X Cocoa : Objective C Classes.

I try to initialize an array of 5 integers variables.

The declaration of the array int tipoDeIVA [5] is located in the interface file ..

> *#import* << Foundation/Foundation.h >>
>
> @interface ArticleObj_EX01 : NSObject
>
> {
>
> @public
>
> int tiposDeIVA;
>
> int tipoDeIVA[5];
>
> }
>
> typedef struct article_structure article_a;

...

...

> -(void) setInitClass
>
> {
>
> ```
> int cont=0;
>
> // the next line give the error called Expected expression, say too "(!) Parse Issue" ..
>
> tipoDeIVA [5]={0,0,0,0,0};
>
> // to get initialize the array I 'need' use a loop for with the next code ..
>
> for (cont=0;cont<5;cont++)
>
>     tipoDeIVA [cont] = 0;
>
> tiposDeIVA = 0;
> ```
>
> }

...

I would like get initialize right arrays with multiple values in a single line of code.

Thanks, Sergio Xavier

Comment: you can't use initialization syntax that way if you've already declared it because it's no longer initialization, it's declaration and then assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialise the array in a single line of code, you have to use the loop you mention:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    tipoDeIVA[i] = 0;
```

Under Objective-C you should probably be using `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` instead.

Also the name of that method looks wrong as a method starting with `set` is expected to be the setter of a `@property`, and it should not start with `init` either, as that is designed for the initializer of the object (that method isn't supposed to be the `init` method is it?).